# Webapp design for internet, intranet and extranet?

Tags: security, best-practices, extranet, intranet, internet

I am a beginner in Sharepoint and I must conceive a Sharepoint solution. I need to have an Intranet for employees as well as an access point for collaborators to a particular site in this intranet. For this part I thought of extending the intranet (claim based auth) and mixing windows auth and form based auth respectively for the employees and collaborators. Collaborators will use credentials stored in the DB. Is this correct ?

My second part is that I need to have an internet website (100% public) that can be modified through the intranet portal. Should it be in a different webapp or not ? If not, can (and should) I extend an internet webapp twice to narrow down the access ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, that sounds right.  You do not need to Extend the Web App in this scenario

2) Yes, different Web Application in order to enable Anonymous access.  You can Extend the Internet Web Application to enable NTLM/Kerberos on a particular Zone to limit access.

Sounds like you have the right idea.

Comment: What do you mean about not extending the webapp ? I thought extending a webapp would allow to publish a part of the intranet to the internet ? Or is it a bit overkill for one site ?

Comment: You do not have to extend a Web App to expose it to your collaborators.  You just need to make sure the Alternate Access Mapping/IIS Binding/DNS/Firewall are all set up to allow access from the Internet to your FBA/Windows-auth Web App.

Comment: Okay, but isn't it easier ? I referred to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648385.aspx

Comment: If you're using SharePoint 2010, you do not need to extend the Web Application in order to accommodate a different type of authentication.  In SharePoint 2007, it was a requirement.